# Are there examples in poetry of previously being contracted to prev'ously?

Tags: contractions, poetry

I'm curious if there are any examples in poetry of the word *previously* being contracted to three syllables, by contracting it to *prev'ously*, or some variant spelling. It would seem that we are keeping the *v* consonant but eliminating the *i* sound. Is this ever done?

Comment: Who knows? In poetry, anything goes. See how charmingly EE Cummings squishes the kids together in [in Just-] https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/47247/in-just

Comment: Generally, the more artificial the device, the less satisfactory the result.

Comment: For poetry, you can treat the word previous as two syllables, even without changing the spelling. Shakespeare seems not to have used the word previous, but he does treat the similar words *glorious* and *curious* as two syllables. He writes "Full many a glorious morning have I seen" and "If my slight Muse do please these curious days," in his sonnets

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks for the tip! That is very good to know.

Answer (score 1):

My cat had mischievously

Scratched the door grievously

Damaging the paint I'd applied prev'ously

:-)

Answer (score 1):

After checking the OED, Google Books, [poetryfoundation.org](https://www.poetryfoundation.org) (via Google), and [EEBO](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?ALLSELECTED=1&xc=1&g=eebogroup&type=simple&rgn=full%20text&q1=Prev%E2%80%99ous*&cite1=&cite1restrict=author&cite2=&cite2restrict=author&singlegenre=All&Submit=Search&c=eebo&c=eebo2), I was not able to find any examples of *prev’ously*.  I was able to find just one example of *prev’ous* though (making it extremely rare):

> While Turks and Pagans, and the stubborn Jews,
>   Had something ￼ prev'ous, helping them to chuse:
>   The last, their Circumcision had before,
>   And learnt only one Deity t'adore,

([Grotius, his arguments for the truth of Christian religion rendred into plain English verse](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A42204.0001.001/1:9?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=Prev%E2%80%99ous*), 1684)

This source is old, and it has many examples of what I would describe as over-the-top use of apostrophes (such as *o'th'*, *w'Examples*, and *liv'd & dy'd, and liv'd*) so I would not really suggest emulating it.

Comment: I wonder if my little effort will ever be indexed :-)